# How to combine list and dict together row by row

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop

I currently have two data where one is a list and one is a dict. Example:

```py
data_1 = {
    '583015': 7,
    '583016': 0,
    '583017': 0,
    '583018': 22,
    '583019': 74,
    '583020': 56,
    '583021': 108,
    '583022': 56,
    '583023': 72,
    '583024': 45,
}

data_2 = [
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4',
    '5',
    '6',
    '7',
    '8',
    '9',
    '10',
]
```

and currently what I have done is that I started to do a

```
for i in data_1:
   print(i)
```

but I quickly understood I couldn't call another for loop for data_2 inside data_1... and im stuck.

My question is how can I make each row for data_1 and data_2 to be combined as the expected result below:

**Expected**:

```
combined = {
    '1': 7,
    '2': 0,
    '3': 0,
    '4': 22,
    '5': 74,
    '6': 56,
    '7': 108,
    '8': 56,
    '9': 72,
    '10': 45
}
```

Comment: Your expected result contains duplicate keys, dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys

Comment: The desired output implies that you assume that the input dictionary is sorted in a specific order, which is generally not the case for dictionaries.

Comment: @IainShelvington I have now updated. I realized that I wouldn't end up having to same keys :) It will always be a unique key but it could be same value.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb I have now updated the thread, please see again. I have removed where it uses duplicatedkeys. It will not be that anymore in this case. It could also be a list or dict, I think I used dict. because it would be easier to print out the key:value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solutoin works for `Python 3.7+`, since in older versions the order of items in dictionary is not guaranteed!

It's achievable using the following code. In order to iterate through dictionary values, use `data_1.values()`.

```py
data_3 = {}

for Index, value in enumerate(data_1.values()):
    data_3[data_2[Index]] = value

print(data_3)
```

To learn more about iterating through a dictionary, [this article on realpython](https://realpython.com/iterate-through-dictionary-python) is a good source.

Comment: Ahhhh this was so smart!! - Of course I could just use the index of data_2... how could I not think about that. Thanks!

Comment: And also for someone who would need this in the future and needs a one liner: `{data_2[Index]: value for Index, value in enumerate(data_1.values())}`